# Xcode compiles ok but Xcodebuild gives linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, clang

I am setting up jenkins for building my ios objective c project with the xcode plugin.  When using the Xcode GUI, the project compiles and runs just fine.

When using either xcodebuild or xctool from the command line, I get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` (a long list) and `linker command failed with exit code 1`. This is a `clang` error; xcodebuild was not yet called according to the log.

Where are the likely causes for error? Where should I look for issues? Our project uses numerous cocoapods and of course has several targets.

Comment: I'd guess library search paths are different and/or the target's dependencies didn't build beforehand.